# Prism PubSubEvent Subscribe not working with certain code

Tags: c#, prism

My view model is this.

```
private string _currentModel;
public string CurrentModel
{
    get { return _currentModel; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _currentModel, value); }
}

public StatsViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, ITester tester)
{
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<ProductChanged>>().Subscribe(x =>
        {                
            CurrentModel = x.Product.Name;
            GetProductStats(x.Product.Id, tester.TesterInfo.Id);

       }, ThreadOption.UIThread);
}
```

When I run this the code in the subscribe does not execute.

So i then kept it simple and changed to this.

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<ProductChanged>>().Subscribe(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("");

}, ThreadOption.UIThread);
```

This works fine. I then started adding the original code back and I added the assignment of the CurrentModel variable but kept it simple like this.

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<ProductChanged>>().Subscribe(x =>
{
    CurrentModel = "Test";

}, ThreadOption.UIThread);
```

This does not work. Any ideas why this is not working?

**UPDATE:**
So I modified the code and set the option of 'keepSubscriberReferenceAlive' to true. Everything now seems to work.

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<ProductChanged>>().Subscribe(x =>
{                
      CurrentModel = x.Product.Name;
      GetProductStats(x.Product.Id, tester.TesterInfo.Id);

 }, ThreadOption.UIThread, true); // <----- added true
```

Any ideas why adding true fixes the issue and why its not required in the 2nd block of code at the top, with just a Console.WriteLine?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens if you put a breakpoint in the subcribe action?

Comment: Not working as in I put a break point in and it never breaks. Only one that breaks is Console.Writeline

Comment: Your subscriber is getting garbage collected before the event is received then.

Comment: Yes but why does it seem dependant on the code inside the subscribe? i.e. Console.WriteLine is not garbage collected but the code in my first conde block is garbage collected.